# Connect other SQL Databases on Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, odbc, azure-sql-database

I want to connect other SQL Databases like SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle on Azure SQL Database. I have found that there is one functionality Elastic Query but using that we can connect to another Azure SQL Databases only.

Is there any way we can achieve this?

For SQL Server, Linked Servers are there. It is working fine. But I need same thing for Azure SQL Servers also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database allows you to connect to Azure SQL Database and to Azure SQL Data Warehouse also using "elastic queries".

The new Azure SQL Database Managed Instance (another PaaS option) supports Linked Server connections to on-premises SQL Server and to Azure SQL Databases. However, linked servers on managed instances do not support to connect to files, Analysis Services, and other RDBMS (like MySQL or Oracle) at this time.

If you need to connect to MySQL or Oracle to query data there, maybe an Azure SQL VM (IaaS) makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks Alberto for answering. I have some databases on SQL Server(Azure VM) and some on Azure SQL Server. I am migrating SQL Server to Azure SQL Server. I was searching an option for Azure Server like Linked Server. But I think there is no such functionality exist. I will use manually connection using Node ODBC Connector. Still thanks for your help.

Comment: That's correct Azure SQL Database does not have linked servers. Only elastic queries allow you to query other Azure SQL Databases.